# Get vimeo thumbnail image through SSL

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Like this image for example: `http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/449/060/449060084_100.jpg`
Youtube is able to give me their images through SSL `https://img.youtube.com/vi/_EvDcmcX0Kk/0.jpg`, but Vimeo doesn't. Probably because they are on CDN hosted on akamai. Is there any way of doing it though ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the host is b.vimeocdn.com you can use https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com/ts/449/060/449060084_100.jpg to access the images over secure.

We are in the process of rolling out a new image system which will use the same host for secure and insecure. If the host of the image is i.vimeocdn.com then you can use https without changing the host.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. Waiting for that feature :)

Comment: this feature is now available, making an https call will return thumbnail urls in https with the same host